# Active Record: Remove element from PostgreSQL array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Assume there's an active record model called `Job` which has an array column `follower_ids`. I have already created a scope which allows to fetch all jobs followed by a user:

```rb
# Returns all jobs followed by the specified user id
def self.followed_by(user_id)
  where(
    Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new(
      '@>',
      Job.arel_table[:follower_ids],
      Arel.sql("ARRAY[#{user_id}]::bigint[]")
    )
  )
end
```

```rb
# Retrieve all jobs followed by user with id=1
Job.followed_by(1)
```

Is there a way to remove specific elements from the `follower_ids` column using the database (i.e., not looping through the active record objects and manually calling `delete`/`save` for each of them)?

For instance, it'd be nice to do something like `Job.followed_by(1).remove_follower(1)` to remove user with `id=1` from all those jobs' `follower_ids` with just one query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended using the PostgreSQL [array_remove](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-array.html) function, which allows to remove a value from an array as follows:

```rb
user_id = 1
update_query = <<~SQL
  follower_ids = ARRAY_REMOVE(follower_ids, :user_id::bigint),
SQL
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql([update_query, { user_id: user_id }])
Job.followed_by(user_id).update_all(sql)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is really a XY problem caused by the fact that you are using an array column where you should be using a join table.

The main reasons you don't want to use an array are:

- If user is deleted you would have to update every row in the jobs table instead of just removing rows in the join table with a cascade or the delete callback.
- No referential integrity.
- Horrible unreadable queries. Its really just a marginal step up from a comma separated string.
- Joins are not really that expensive. "Premature optimzation is the root of all evil".
- You can't use ActiveRecord associations with array columns.

Create the join model with `rails g model following user:references job:references`. And then setup the assocations:

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followers,
    through: :followings,
    source: :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :followings
  has_many :followed_jobs,
    source: :job,
    through: :followings,
    class_name: 'Job'
end
```

To select jobs followed by a user you just do a inner join:

```
user.followed_jobs
```

To get jobs that are not followed you do an outer join on followings where the user id is nil or not equal to `user_id`.

```
fui = Following.arel_table[:user_id]
Job.left_joins(:followings)
   .where(fui.eq(nil).or(fui.not_eq(1)))
```

If you want to unfollow a job you just remove the row from `followings`:

```
Following.find_by(job: job, user: user).destroy
# or 
job.followings.find_by(user: user).destroy
# or
user.followings.find_by(job: job).destroy
```

You can automatically do this with the when the job or user is destroyed with the `dependent:` option.